# Canvas (onDraw) Android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I have been trying to draw different rectangles on the canvas after several times of button click. It should display different colored rectangle and the rectangle should remain on canvas after every button click. The rectangles should be able to move around the canvas. I have written the View class but i have no idea how to implement the onDraw() method on activity after a button click and also no idea of ways to create different color of rectangle.

I have 4 buttons on my main.xml file.

```
public class DrawRectangle extends View {

public DrawRectangle(Context context){

    super(context);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect ourRect = new Rect();

    ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

    Paint blue = new Paint();

    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    //Draw to actual canvas
    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);

}
```

}

This is my activity class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bluebutton, redbutton, yellowbutton, greenbutton;
DrawRectangle dr;
Canvas canvas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dr = new DrawRectangle(this);

    bluebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
    redbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redbutton);
    yellowbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yellowbutton);
    greenbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.greenbutton);



bluebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dr.onDraw();
    }
});
}
```

}

Do i have to implement the onTouchListener as well so that the rectangles can move around?

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to invalidate the canvas in your onClick method for each button. Add a few boolean variables to tell the onDraw method what color to draw.

```
public static boolean isBlue, isRed, isYellow, isGreen;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button bluebutton, redbutton, yellowbutton, greenbutton;
    DrawRectangle dr;
    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    dr = new DrawRectangle(this);

    bluebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
    redbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.redbutton);
    yellowbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yellowbutton);
    greenbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.greenbutton);

    boolean blueColor = false;
    bluebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isBlue = true;
        isRed = false;
        isGreen = false;
        isYellow = false;
        dr.invalidate();
    }
    });
}
```

The update the onDraw method to check to see what color to draw.

```
//Used for storing rectangles        
public static List<Rect> rectangles;
public class DrawRectangle extends View {

    public DrawRectangle(Context context){

    super(context);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //Draw previous rectangles
    for(int i=0;i<rectangles.size();i++){
        canvas.drawRect(rectangles.get(i), paintColor );
    }
    Rect ourRect = new Rect();

    ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

    Paint paintColor = new Paint();

    if(MainActivity.isBlue){
        paintColor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    paintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    //Draw to actual canvas
    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, paintColor );
    rectangles.add(ourRect)
```

}
}

In order to draw more Rectangles, you should store the previously drawn Rectangles in a Vector and loop through it each time you invalidate the onDraw method.

Comment: thank you for your reply and advice. I have made amendments to my codes but however when the button is click the rectangle is not drawn. Question, do i have to specify a surfaceView on my xml?

Comment: I have set the setContentView(); to be = setContentView(dr); and rectangle is drawn. however the 4 buttons went missing. How do i keep both the buttons and rectangle?

Comment: Can you provide your main.xml file please?

Comment: i have managed to get it work out. If you dont mind could you elaborate on the vector to store previously drawn rectangle part? I can make use of List<Rect> ListOfRect = new ArrayList<Rect>(); or Rectangle r = new Rectangle(); to store? I can also use this method for storing images right?

Comment: Also, right now the rectangle appears only once when the button is click. How can i code it in such way that even if the button is click twice, two rectangle would appear?

Comment: List<Rect> will work great for what you need. Each time you invalidate the canvas, you can loop through the ArrayList and draw the rectangles again. I updated my answer with some code showing a possible way to do this.

Comment: i saw your updates version of your answer and i had tried it out. But it doesnt work:( Could it be that the new rectangle overlaps with the old one thats why i cant see the second added rectangle?

Comment: @pancakeleh the rectangles might be overlapping. If you need, I can create a github sample project that will provide you the functionality you're requesting. Just let me know.

Comment: yes please. I am self learning developing android application and hope that you can help me out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

yes you have to   `onTouchEvent` in your view subclass. you can read the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). The event parameter contains information about the kind of touch you are getting (`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`) and contains also the coordinates of the touch events. 
When you get the ACTION_MOVE event you can change the position of the rectangle and call `invalidate()` to redraw. Plese get rid on the draw call inside the `onClickListener` in your activity